# Tricky PivotTable vlookup in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vlookup

I can't get my head around this problem I have without using VBA which I want to avoid. I have a sheet with a pivottable. The pivottable shows a list of projects and under each project the people who have reported their hours. I want the column next to each person to show the sum of all hours for that project and person and therefore I thought of using VLookup with multiple criterion or with index/match. The problem is that the number of persons differs from every project, and if the pivottable gets updated I don't want the vlookup function to be fixed to the wrong column. Every project contains a "[" and every person a "(", so those are possible characters to search for in a function.

Any ideas on how to solve this, if it's even possible? My dream would be to also add two empty rows after each person.

Comment: It seems like you could find this info in the pivot table, rather than adding a formula for each person/project.  Can you provide a photo or more detailed description of your pivot table?

Comment: Oh, your right! When I changed the pivottable to take "sum" and not "count" it worked. Thanks!!